# Why MultiThread is slower than Single?? (Linux,C,using pthread)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a question with MultiThread.
This code is simple Example about comparing Single Thread vs MultiThread.
(sum 0~400,000,000 with singlethread vs 4-multiThread)

```
//Single
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define NUM_THREAD 4
#define MY_NUM 100000000

void* calcThread(void* param);
double total = 0;
double sum[NUM_THREAD] = { 0, };
int main() {
    long p[NUM_THREAD] = {MY_NUM, MY_NUM * 2,MY_NUM * 3,MY_NUM * 4 };
    int i;
    long total_nstime;
    struct timespec begin, end;
    pthread_t tid[NUM_THREAD];
    pthread_attr_t attr[NUM_THREAD];
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &begin);
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++) {
        calcThread((void*)p[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++) {
        total += sum[i];
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    printf("total = %lf\n", total);
    total_nstime = (end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) * 1000000000 + (end.tv_nsec -    begin.tv_nsec);
    printf("%.3fs\n", (float)total_nstime / 1000000000);
    return 0;
}
void* calcThread(void* param) {
    int i;
    long to = (long)(param);
    int from = to - MY_NUM + 1;
    int th_num = from / MY_NUM;
    for (i = from; i <= to; i++)
        sum[th_num] += i;
    }
```

I wanna change  using 4-MultiThread Code, so I changed that calculate function to using MultiThread.

```
...
int main() {
    ...
    //createThread
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++) {
        pthread_attr_init(&attr[i]);
        pthread_create(&tid[i],&attr[i],calcThread,(void *)p[i]);
    }
    //wait
    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREAD;i++){
        pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++) {
        total += sum[i];
    }   
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    ...
}
```

[Result(in Ubuntu)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVFuY.png)
But,It's slower than Single Function Code. I know MultiThread is faster.
I have no idea with this problem :( What's wrong?
Could you give me some advice ? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "*I know MultiThread is faster*". That isn't always and automatically true. It's not that simple. In this case for example the thread function is CPU bound. So depending on how many cores your system has and how the OS schedules the threads, adding more threads may not help and may even hurt (due to scheduling overhead). For starters, check the scheduling - look at what cores the threads end up running on.

Comment: Fwiw, running **release** optimized builds, my rig (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, clang14.0, i9-11900k) I get 0.304s single-threaded, and 0.083s 4-threaded. You tested this with release builds, *right* ??

Comment: Thanks for comment!
my rig ( Ubuntu , AMD Ryzen 5 3600 ). How can I running optimized build?  I just compile with gcc like "gcc -o test02 test02.c -lpthread"

Comment: Any compiler worth using will replace the `for` loop in `calcThread` with `sum[th_num] += from * 100000000.0 + 4999999950000000.0;` -- one multiply and two adds.  So it will likely be faster than the overhead of creating new threads.

Comment: @Doge `gcc -O2 -o test02 test02.c -lpthread`

Comment: @ChrisDood Thats really good idea! Thanks a lot :) !

Comment: @kaylum  Its really hard :( .. I need to study more about scheduling .Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I know MultiThread is faster"

This isn't always the case, as generally you would be CPU bound in some way, whether that be due to core count, how it is scheduled at the OS level, and hardware level.

It is a balance how many threads is worth giving to a process, as you may run into an old Linux problem where you would be spending more time scheduling the processes than actually running them.

As this is very hardware and OS dependant, it is difficult to say exactly what the issue may be, but make sure you have the appropriate microcode for your CPU installed (generally installed by default in Ubuntu), but just in case, try:

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode
```

Otherwise look at what other processes are being run, and it may be that a lot of other things are running on the cores that are being allocated the process.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! 
MultiThread Programming is too hard :( ...